# Optional parameter with UML class diagram

Tags: uml

Is there an official syntax for specifying optional parameter of a method in UML class type diagram?

For example, I have a method:

```
public function abc( $arg = 0) { ... return void; }
```

How would I indicate that $arg is an optional parameter and its default value?

Comment: Is it "[variable_name : data_type = default_value]" ?

Comment: In UML we use the term `Operation` for what you call `Method`.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Hehe, search for `method`  in Superstructures :-)

Comment: @ThomasKilian the `Method` is the `Behavior` that implements the `Operation`. In this case we are talking about the specification and not the implementation so `Operation`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UML 2.5 has following definition for a parameterlist

> - `<parameter-list> is a list of Parameters of the Operation in the following format: <parameter-list> ::= <parameter> [‘,’<parameter>]*
>     <parameter> ::= [<direction>] <parameter-name> ‘:’ <type-expression>
>     [‘[‘<multiplicity>’]’] [‘=’ <default>] [‘{‘ <parm-property> [‘,’
>     <parm-property>]* ‘}’]`
>
> where:
>
> - `<direction> ::= ‘in’ | ‘out’ | ‘inout’ (defaults to ‘in’ if omitted).`
> - `<parameter-name> is the name of the Parameter.`
> - `<type-expression> is an expression that specifies the type of the Parameter.`
> - `<multiplicity> is the multiplicity of the Parameter. (See MultiplicityElement – sub clause 7.5).`
> - `<default> is an expression that defines the value specification for the default value of the Parameter.`
> - `<parm-property> indicates additional property values that apply to the Parameter.`

So you can use

`+ abc($arg : Integer = 0)`

The type expression is not optional so you can't leave that out, but I guess you can think of a convention where you use something like `Unspecified`

Comment: Probably you need to write `+ abc($arg : Integer[0..1] = 0)` to show the optionality?

Comment: You might, but the multiplicity is optional, so you are allowed to omit it. If a parameter has a default value I guess it implies the fact that it is optional.

Comment: `Integer[0..1]` would mean that the method doesn't require value in `$arg` at all, but it will always have one, either provided from you, or from the default value.

Answer (score 0):

From the UML 2.5 specs chap. 9.4.3.4 Parameters p. 107:

> A Parameter is a specification of an argument used to pass information into or out of an invocation of a BehavioralFeature. The Type and Multiplicity of a Parameter restrict what values may be passed, how many, and whether the values are ordered. The Multiplicity defines a lower and upper bound on the values passed to the Parameter at runtime. A lower bound of zero means the Parameter is optional. Actions using the Parameter may execute without having a value for optional Parameters. A lower bound greater than zero means values for the Parameter are required to arrive sometime during the execution of the action.
>
> If a defaultValue is specified for a Parameter, then it is evaluated at invocation time and used as the argument for this Parameter if and only if no argument is supplied at invocation of the BehavioralFeature.

However, multiplicity is usually not shown on class diagram presentation. The information is just stored in the metadata. At least I have never seen any tool using the notation pointed out by Geert's answer.